# Changing Controls of a form inside a panel

Tags: vb.net, winforms, forms, visual-studio-2010, panels

I am facing a weird problem
I have 3 forms: `MainForm`, `Form1`, `Form2`
`MainForm` has 1 Panel: `Panel1`
`Form1` has 1 Label: `NameLbl` and Button: `ChangeBtn`
`Form2` has 1 textbox: `NameTxt` and Button: `SaveBtn`

I used the following code to open `form1` inside `Panel1` in `mainform`

```
 Panel1.Controls.Clear()
 Dim FormInPanel As New Form1()
 FormInPanel.TopLevel = False
 Panel1.Controls.Add(FormInPanel)
 FormInPanel.Show()
```

On `ChangeBtn.Click` `Form2` opens as `showdialog`
I want `NameLbl.tex`t to change to `NameLbl.text` when `SaveBtn` is clicked But normal code doesnt work.

```
Private Sub SaveBtn_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles SaveBtn.Click
    Form1.NameLbl.text=NameTxt.text
End Sub
```

What Should I do? Any suggestions? Given that i need to open the forms in panels for certain reasons.
Please keep in mind that this is just an example. I have multiple controls in Form1 which i want to change on form2.SaveBtn.click
I have also tried this but it does nothing

```
Private Sub SaveBtn_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles SaveBtn.Click

    For Each c As Control In MainForm.Panel1.Controls(0).Controls
        If c.Name="NameLbl" Then
            c.Text = NameTxt.Text
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Please Somebody tell me how it do it!

Comment: how public are your labels/forms defined? Did you get a build error?

Answer (score 0):

Form2 doesn't seem to have any connection back to Form1 or MainForm. You'd need to raise an event from Form2 which MainForm handles or another class handles and can pass to MainForm

Edit:

Sorry, I've just seen how you're calling Form2. There are lots of ways to get a value back from Form2 after calling ShowDialog(). One is to create a property called Result and check Result if ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK. Something like the following.

```
Public Class Form2
    Inherits System.Windows.Forms.Form
    Public Property Result() As String
        Get
            Return m_Result
        End Get
        Set
            m_Result = Value
        End Set
    End Property
    Private m_Result As String
End Class

Public Class Form1
    Inherits System.Windows.Forms.Form
    Public ChangeBtn As Button
    Public NameLbl As Label
    Public Sub New()
        Me.ChangeBtn = New Button()
        AddHandler Me.ChangeBtn.Click, AddressOf ChangeBtn_Click
        Me.NameLbl = New Label()
    End Sub

    Private Sub ChangeBtn_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
        Dim form As New Form2()
        Dim dr = New form.ShowDialog()
        If dr = DialogResult.OK Then
            Me.NameLbl.Text = form.Result
        End If
    End Sub
End Class
```

I'd like to add that if you plan on growing this application much larger you'll run into issues with maintenance. Look into some patterns for dealing with UI logic like MVC, MVP, MVVM if you're interested.

Comment: Thanks, ran it through the developerfusion converter

Comment: I need it to be a windows forms app. And I want to make it Single window interface. So i thought opening forms in panels will be the best option.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this code:

```
Private Sub SaveBtn_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles SaveBtn.Click
   panel1.Controls(0).NameLbl.text=NameTxt.text '"0" is the index of forminpanel in panel1,maybe it need to change.
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

*Form1* is contained in *Panel1*, so you can not access it via

```
  Form1.
```

Only *MainForm* is visible from *Form2*:

```
Private Sub SaveBtn_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles SaveBtn.Click
    For Each c As Control In MainForm.Panel1.Controls(0).Controls
        If TypeOf c Is TextBox Then
            c.Text = NameTxt.Text
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: I have multiple controls in Form1 which i want to change from Form2. In my question i just gave an example. With your code i am not being able to address specific controls.

Comment: @SubhajitMukherjee You had a question and gave you an answer. Then you say it is just an example, and need something else. I am not going to play this game.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
For Each form1 As Form1 In MainForm.OwnedForms.OfType(Of Form1)
    Form1.NameLbl.text = NameTxt.text
Next
```

Answer (score 0):

I've faced same issue and I've fixed with this

```
     Dim f As FormInPanel
     f = Form.Panel1.Controls(0)
     f.transection = True
     f.NameLbl.text=NameTxt.text
```